# jQuery mobile button icon position too far left

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using JQM 1.4.2 and trying to get the button icons closer to the Text when using the class .ui-btn-icon-left.

I took a screen shot and modified the the list icon the way I want it to look in the middle button.  I just cant seem to get the icon off the left side at all.  using padding just changed the top and bottom.

What class do I need to use to accomplish this?

```
<div data-role="navbar" >        
        <ul id="navfooter">
            <li><a href="#home"  class="ui-nodisc-icon ui-icon-home ui-btn-center ui-btn-active ui-state-persist svbtn"  data-transition="slide">Tour</a></li>
            <li><a  class="ui-nodisc-icon ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-left svbtn"  href="#listViewPage"  data-transition="slide" >List</a></li>
            <li><a  class="ui-nodisc-icon ui-icon-location ui-btn-icon-left svbtn" href="#map-page" data-transition="slide" >Map</a></li>                
        </ul>
    </div>
```

[image]

Here is the image of what it now looks like after adding the css

```
.ui-icon-home::after {
position: relative;
left:10px;   
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the left position of the icons within the button:

```
.ui-navbar a:after {
    left: 20% !important;
}
```

However, this will allow the icon and text to overlap as the buttons get smaller.

A better way to achieve this might be to put the icons inline with the text. You put a span in front of the text with CSS to place the icon. To control the distance between the icon and the text, tweak the margin-right attribute:

```
<div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="ui-icon-alert ui-btn-icon-notext inlineIcon"></span>Summary</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active"><span class="ui-icon-star ui-btn-icon-notext inlineIcon"></span>Favs</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="ui-icon-gear ui-btn-icon-notext inlineIcon"></span>Setup</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

.inlineIcon {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 6px;
}
```

If you want icons in black with no disc behind them add the ui-alt-icon class to the span and change the CSS to get rid of the disc:

```
<div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="ui-alt-icon ui-icon-alert ui-btn-icon-notext inlineIconNoDisk"></span>Summary</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active"><span class="ui-alt-icon ui-icon-star ui-btn-icon-notext inlineIconNoDisk"></span>Favs</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="ui-alt-icon ui-icon-gear ui-btn-icon-notext inlineIconNoDisk"></span>Setup</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

.inlineIconNoDisk {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 6px;
}
.inlineIconNoDisk:after {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/j5m4Lwtt/1/)** showing all 3 options

Comment: Thanks, this did pretty good.  My icons are not as close to the text as yours are in the demo for some reason.

Comment: @BGecko, make the margin-right smaller than 6px, you can even use negative numbers if the disc is hidden: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/j5m4Lwtt/2/

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the home icon you're looking to move, applying the following to that icon should fix it but it's hard to say what the best solution is without seeing the menu in action.

```
.ui-icon-home::after {
    left: (amount to shift left)px;
}
```

Note that ::after applies styling to just the icon, whereas ".ui-icon-home" applies to the entire anchor element. Again, if you could link to a pastebin or similar, it would be easier to give you a better answer.

Comment: I want all the icons in the nav bar to be the same.

Comment: just tried it. The icon moves closer to the Text in the correct position but it now sits below it a little.  I changed the left: attr and it really didnt do anything.  Took it out all together and still the same, aligned just below bottom of text.

Comment: Sorry there, the relative positioning is at fault for that. I've updated my answer; hopefully that fixed it.